# product collection still show not in stock products

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, product-collection, collection-filtering, related-products

Hi I'm going crazy with this function. Although I added In stock Filter, it still return Not in Stock products. Where I'm wrong ?

```
public function getRelatedProducts($limit = false) {
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');

        if ($category = Mage::registry('current_category')) {

        } elseif ($product) {
            $ids = $product->getCategoryIds();

            if (!empty($ids)) {
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($ids[0]);
            }
        }

        if ($category) {
            if ($limit === false) {
                $limit = Mage::getStoreConfig('autorelated/general/limit');
            }

            $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(
                    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                ))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', 1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0))
                ->addAttributeToFilter ('price', array ('gt' => 1))
                ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->setPageSize($limit);

            Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);


            if ($product) {
                $products->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array(
                    'neq' => Mage::registry('current_product')->getId())
                );
            }

            $products->getSelect()->order('updated_at','desc');



        } else {
            return false;
        }

    return $products;
}
```

Comment: try to re-indexing

Comment: I tried a lot of times, I tried to clear cache, everything. but it still doesn't work. I really don't know what to do .. I'm going crazy

Comment: have you found solution?  i am still finding.  let me know if you have found solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Way 1:**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->joinField('qty',
                 'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                 'qty',
                 'product_id=entity_id',
                 '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                 'left')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0));
```

**Way 2:**

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
```

Comment: it's incredible.. still doesn't work.

Comment: have you found solution of it?   i am facing same issue.  i tried way 1 and way 2 to my collection but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use below 5 line of code for in stock product collection:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED));

Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);

zend_debug::dump($productCollection->getData());
```

Comment: return array(0) { }

Comment: My mistake. I have edited the code.

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
  despite this code it shows out of stock products in product collection.    not removing the out of stock products